# Constrained trace optimization with relavance to optimal asset selection

Tags: linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-equations, mathematical-finance

Let $D$ and $Q$ be two real $m\times m$ diagonal matrices given
$$
D=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
d_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & d_2 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & d_m
\end{array}\right)
$$
$$
Q=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
q_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & q_2 & \cdots & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cdots & q_m
\end{array}\right)
$$

further assume that $d_i>0$ and $q_i>0$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,m\}$.

Optimization Problem:
$$
\max_A \operatorname{Tr} \left(\left(A^T D^2 A\right)^{1/2} \right)
$$

subject to the constraint that
$$
(A^{\intercal}A)^2 =A^{\intercal}Q^2 A
$$
where the decision variable $A$ is a real $m\times m$ matrix.

The optimal $A^{*}$ is not unique in this setting. The question is, what is it possible to say about the optimal $A$? In particular;
is it possible to show that among the optimal matrices there exists
an optimal $A^{**}$ , such that there is exactly 1 nonzero entry
in each row of $A^{**}$.

(I believe this is true for $m=2$, but unclear if it would hold for
$m>2$).

Some notes on the problem:

1. $\operatorname{Tr} \left((A^{\intercal}D^{2}A)^{1/2}\right) = \operatorname{Tr} \left((DAA^{\intercal}D)^{1/2}\right)$
2. The optimal solution is not unique. For example, for any unitary
   matrix, $U$ where $UU^T=I$ then for $\bar{A}=AU$
   \begin{align}
   \operatorname{Tr}\left((A^{\intercal}D^{2}A)^{1/2}\right) & =\operatorname{Tr} \left((\bar{A}^{\intercal}D^{2}\bar{A})^{1/2}\right) \text{ and }\\
   (A^{\intercal}A)^{2}=A^{\intercal}Q^{2}A & \Rightarrow(\bar{A}^{\intercal}\bar{A})^2 = \bar{A}^{\intercal} Q^2 \bar{A}
   \end{align}
3. If $A$ is full rank then $AA^{\intercal}=Q^2$ and $\operatorname{Tr}\left((DAA^{\intercal}D)^{1/2}\right)=\sum_{i=1}^m d_i q_i$.
4. It is not always optimal for $A$ to be full rank. For example, let $d_1=q_2=2$ and $d_2=q_1=1/2$.

Here if $A$ is full rank then $\operatorname{Tr} \left((DAA^{\intercal}D)^{1/2} \right)=2.$
However, if
$$
A=\alpha\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
where $\alpha=\sqrt{4.25}/2$. (from the constrain).

Then
$$
(A^{\intercal}D^{2}A)^{1/2}=\alpha\left(\begin{array}{cc}
\sqrt{4.25} & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
and so $\operatorname{Tr} \left((A^{\intercal}D^{2}A)^{1/2} \right) = 2.125>2$.

In contrast, if $d_1\geq d_2$ and $q_1\geq q_2$ then the optimal solution is for $A$ to be full rank.

PS: Any help in improving the title appreciated

Comment: http://quant.stackexchange.com